# How to create a TFRecord from a NumPy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, tensorflow

I'd like to 1. iterate through a directory of images and turn each image into a NumPy array. I think I have accomplished this with the following code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import os

myimages = []

path_to_images = 'images_animation'
filenum = len([name for name in os.listdir(path_to_images) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path_to_images, name))])

#loops through available pngs
for p in range(1, filenum):

    ## Read in picture
    fname = "images_animation/image%03d.png" % p
    img = mpimg.imread(fname)
    imgplot = plt.imshow(img)

    # append AxesImage object to the list
    myimages.append([imgplot])

for n, im in enumerate(myimages):
    img = Image.open(fname).convert("L")
    arr = np.array(img
    print(arr)
```

If I can make this code better or more efficient, please feel free to tell me how.

Now, I'd like to 2. turn these NumPy arrays into TFRecords. What is the best way to do so? I'm near clueless as how to do this, so I have not done much to solve it myself, so I'm looking for a solution.

Comment: Please read the tag excerpts for tags you're trying to use on a question. [tensor]+[flow] don't make for [tensorflow]. Please [edit] your question. Also add what you've done yourself in trying to solve your problem; "*Please provide code*" is never enough effort.

Comment: I've taken into account your advice and suggestions. Thanks.

Comment: Did you get answers to convert numpy nd array to tfrecord efficiently? I have code to convert numpy array to tfrecord. But it converts single array to Example and then write serialized string one by one. It is very slow (15x slower than numpy.save). I am looking for efficient code to convert it.